Unable to get date in React Native
I have been looking everywhere to a solution to this problem which I've been on for hours now. I am trying to get a date in my React Native expo app. However keep getting error
ERROR  TypeError: constructor is not callable


Below is my simple implementation
const App = () => {
 const today = new Date();
 console.log("date", today);

return (
    <View>
       <Text>
         {today}
       </Text>
    </View>
   )
}
 

And also my package.json:
{
  "name": "scoreboard-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Is there something wrong with the Date function? Or does expo not support this?
But im sure this is a JS specific function which should have nothing to do with expo or RN
Thanks

Quick question, what do you get if you do console.log(Date)? Is there a possibility you could have overwritten the Date global? Maybe you imported something in that file named Date?

Generally speaking that means you have a variable Date that is hiding the class Date. You should check out your code to see if you have accidently done this.

@moonstar-x it doesnt let me get to the console log, just goes straight to the error

@scrappedcola Im using date as a key in some of my objects. However its spelled with lowercase date where the Date() is uppercase. Im basically trying to assign my object keys to >> date: new Date()

You should be able to remove the new Date() statement and instead do a console.log(Date). The idea is to check what is Date referring to because the most likely cause of this issue is that you have overwritten your Date global with something else.

@moonstar-x the output of console.log(Date) >>>  LOG  {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.forward_ref), "attrs": [], "inlineStyle": {"rules": ["font-size: 10px;", "font-weight: bold;"]}, "render": [Function g], "shouldForwardProp": undefined, "styledComponentId": true, "target": {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.forward_ref), "render": [Function anonymous]}}

Do you have an import of a React component named Date in the file?

@moonstar-x I have tried to import, however not sure where to import from as intellisense doesnt provide options

No no, I mean that in your file you have already an import named Date that is referring to a React component. If you have something like import Date from 'library' replace it with import DateComponent from 'library'. If you have a import { Date } from 'library' replace it with import { Date as DateComponent } from 'library'.

@moonstar-x oh no, I don't have an imports of Date at all. I tried importing it but there was nothing to import. So I just tried using it directly const date = new Date() as I assumed it was a global function that didn't need to be imported

Trying this out in an Expo Snack does reproduce the error. You can fix this by stringifying the Date object before passing it to the Text component.
const App = () => {
 const today = new Date().toString();
 console.log("date", today);

return (
    <View>
       <Text>
         {today}
       </Text>
    </View>
   )
}

React expects the child to be a string / React component, and not a Date object.
Ref: Unable to display Date in JSX in ReactJS

Today is an object which can not be displayed in  tags you use functions like .getFullYear().... to get the value in the form of a string for example if you want to display the year
 const App = () => {
 const today = new Date();
 console.log("date", today);

return (
    <View>
       <Text>
         {today.getFullYear()}
       </Text>
    </View>
   )
}


If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review
